# Como copiar um arquivo em Python?

Tags: python, arquivo

Como copiar um arquivo `fonte` para um arquivo `destino` em Python?

Comment: @downvoter Por quê?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### [`shutil.copyfile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfile)

```
import shutil
shutil.copyfile(fonte, destino)
```

É possível utilizar `os.path` para obter caminhos que funcionem para diversos sistemas operacionais.

Por exemplo, para mover o arquivo `arquivo.txt` para o diretório `dir`, basta fazer:

```
import shutil
import os
shutil.copyfile(fonte, os.path.join(destino,'dir'))
```

Caso o diretório não exista ou não seja acessível, irá ocorrer uma exceção do tipo `IOError`.

Se o arquivo de destino já existir, será sobrescrito.

O `shutil.copyfile` só copia o conteúdo dos arquivos e ignora metadados.

O `destino` precisa ser um nome de arquivo e não pode ser um diretório.

### [`shutil.copy`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.copy)

```
import shutil
shutil.copy(fonte, destino)
```

O `shutil.copy` é parecido com o `shutil.copyfile`, mas aceita um diretório como destino. Neste caso, se o destino não tiver um nome de arquivo, o mesmo nome de arquivo da `fonte` será utilizado na pasta de `destino`.

### [`shutil.copy2`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.copy2)

```
import shutil
shutil.copy2(fonte, destino)
```

O `shutil.copy` tem o mesmo comportamento do `shutil.copy2`, mas também copia os metadados.