# Copiar arquivo para um diretório Windows , utilizando Python

Tags: python

Ao tentar copiar um arquivo para um diretório do Windows recebo acesso negado, existe alguma forma de contornar isso?

O código funciona se for em outro diretório, exemplo " Area de Trabalho"

```
import shutil

source=r'C:\Users\Douglas Fabiano\Desktop\VisualStudioCode\origem\chrome.admx'
destination=r'C:\Windows\PolicyDefinitions\chrome.admx'
shutil.copy(source, destination)
```

> PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\Windows\PolicyDefinitions\chrome.admx'

Comment: Para manipular arquivos em pastas protegidas ou de sistema tem que rodar o script como administrador ou um usuário que possua privilégios para realizar a operação na pasta.

Answer (score -2):

Como Augusto Vasques informou para manipular arquivos em pastas protegidas ou de sistema tem que rodar o script como administrador ou um usuário que possua privilégios para realizar a operação na pasta ou arquivos.

Você pode digitar "CMD" em pesquisar e executar como administrador se seu usuário tiver esse privilégio caso contrario terá que pedir acesso para o administrador do sistema.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Depois basta ir até a pasta do projeto usando "cd" comando usado para navegar entre os diretório e locais físicos ou virtuais no sistema
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Com o privilégio basta digitar "nome-arquivo.py" para chamar o aplicativo no meu caso, mas pode ser "python nome-arquivo.py" com isso conseguirá executar a ação caso o arquivo exista na origem.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O código que criei para teste :

```py
#
import shutil
#
# cpFileVS-admx.py - Nome do arquivo
onde_estou='cpFileVS-admx'
#

try:
    # Mensagem para informa que iniciou o código 
    print('Iniciando cópia...')
    # Aqui informa o local do arquivo de origem a ser copiado ex:/home/o/file.txt ou c:\user\o\file.txt
    source=r'C:\Users\Douglas Fabiano\Desktop\VisualStudioCode\origem\chrome.admx'
    # Aqui informa o local do arquivo de destino a ser salvo ex:/home/d/file.txt ou c:\user\d\file.txt
    destination=r'C:\Windows\PolicyDefinitions\chrome.admx'
    # Executa a cópia
    shutil.copy(source, destination)
    # Mensagem para informar que encerrou o código
    print('Fim da cópia!','Verificar a existência do arquivo...')

# Exceções. *Como há uma ordem se houver uma exceção as primeiras serão verificadas. 
# Caso adicione e conheça os erros possiveis é bom deixar "except Exception" por ultimo para algum erro desconhecido.
# Informando que essa prática só uso para testes
except FileNotFoundError as err:
    print('Arquivo não pode ser encontrado.','ERROR#'+onde_estou+':',err)
except PermissionError as err:
    print('Não pode copiar. Execute como administrador.', 'ERROR#'+onde_estou+':',err)
except Exception as err:
    print('ERROR#'+onde_estou+':',err)
```

[Como copiar um arquivo em Python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/150000/como-copiar-um-arquivo-em-python?rq=1)

Comment: Tem algo errado, falta informações ou a resposta é inútil por ser negativado?